# Get the url that a user is coming from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

If an user is coming from an specific page i need to do get some values out of a cookie and change what the users sees.

Now, the issue is that i cannot find a way to view what page the user is coming from.

EDIT: This is intended to capture when the users clicks back in a page and save the state of the previous page.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Solved. Every time i load a page i'm saving the url, so when i get to this page i just have to read it to tell. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use browser history in our javascript or you can write your last page in cookies and get the last link then update it

Answer (score 2):

Using cookies will indeed fix this for you. So when a user goes to a new page - set a cookie like:

```
app.controller('myController',['$scope', '$location', $cookies], function($scope, $location, $cookies){
  if($cookies.get('page') == '/index'){
     //do stuff if user came from index
  }

  $scope.pageChanged = function(value){
    $cookies.put('page', value);
    $location.path('/index');
  }
}
```

just make sure you use the `pageChanged` function to set your page every time user changes pages.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) you can use the `resolve` function to detect when a new route has been loaded.

Another way would be to listen for the event `$routeChangeSuccess`or `$routeChangeError` and get the information needed from the service `$location` or `$route`.

If you want a sample just ask me, I'll try to post one as soon as I have free time.